# How to provide a favicon to a Tomcat webapp which is not served on root in order to avoid browser's 404s on /favicon.ico

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, url-routing, favicon

For an intranet project I have a Tomcat serving a website under `http://myserver.local:1234/boilergraphs/index.html`

I develop new features for this webapp in Eclipse. For debugging I am  using heavily the Web Developer Tools of the external browsers Chrome and Firefox. Both browsers test automatically for http://myserver.local:1234//favicon.ico - and give me 404 errors in the developer console due to the fact that the URL doesn't exist. This console output is quite distracting because I watch the console for *other*, development-related errors.

How can I tell my Tomcat instance (inside Eclipse) to serve a `favicon.ico` on http://myserver.local:1234/favicon.ico, while the only app on the Tomcat system is the `boilergraphs` app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't if the only app is your `boilergraphs` app. You'll need to have a second web app with your `favicon.ico` file, to open the server editor for your instance in the **Servers View**, and deploy the other web app to a path of `/`. Tomcat itself ships with such an app in its `webapp/ROOT` folder.

[image: Server instance context menu in the Servers View]

[image: Modules page in the Server editor, showing a second app deployed to /]

Answer (score 1):

A totally different way to get rid of the 404 error cluttering your developer console, is to provide a favicon *in* the HTML of the page. This has the advantage that you do not need to fiddle just for the favicon with added files and routing.

Here an example(*); just add to the HTML page (say, `index.html`) between the `<head> ... </head>` tags:

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAAAAAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEhEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP7/AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

---

(*) Credit: [favicon.cc](https://www.favicon.cc/?action=icon&file_id=659959)